# How to create an association table and determine lift

Tags: python, r

So I have an excel file with 7000 symptoms and more information in the other columns, but I want to focus on the first column named "symptom", an example is the following:

1. Pain
2. Sneezing
3. Coughing
4. Bleeding

I want to create an association table (where everything is crossed) like:

1. Pain - Sneezing
2. Pain - Coughing
3. Pain - Bleeding
4. Sneezing - Coughing
5. Sneezing - bleeding
6. Coughing - bleeding

The next thing that I would like to achieve is to add a confidence and lift.

I tried using a pandas dataframe, but after making an association table, I achieve 59million rows. And this can't be added to the excel.

In the end, I would like to get an excel file where the 2 first columns are the 2 cross symptoms, then there is a column for the confidence, and then there is a column for the lift.
All results in the excel should be above conf 0.6 because otherwise there would be too many rows in the excel.

Comment: You can use `apriori` algorithm, a classical data mining tool for association. The R package that allows that analysis is [arules](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html). It's hard to help further without any data or code (and your question risks to be closed).

Comment: Where does the data of 'confidence' and 'lift' for all the matches come from?

Comment: The confidence and lift are calculated from the same excel (f.e. transactions containing a & b / transactions containing a)